# Override WordPress core post-template.php block template

Tags: posts, wp-query, custom-field, block-editor

I need to modify the default markup generated using the `render_block_core_post_template` function located inside wp-includes > blocks > post-template.php.

I don't see any other way of modifying the markup so i can insert a custom field.

Is it possible to override this core template via a theme or plugin? If so, where to start.

```
function register_block_core_post_template() {
    register_block_type_from_metadata(
        __DIR__ . '/post-template',
        array(
            'render_callback'   => 'render_block_core_post_template',
            'skip_inner_blocks' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_block_core_post_template' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**To insert a custom field:**

I recommend using the [Meta Field Block plugin](https://cs.wordpress.org/plugins/display-a-meta-field-as-block/) developed just for this purpose

**To alter `core/post-template`'s DOM with PHP**

Add a filter to render_block action e.g. in functions.php

```
// Replace post-template block with custom DOM
add_filter( 'render_block', 'MyPostTemplate' , 10, 2 );

function MyPostTemplate( $block_content, $block )
{
    // bypass if other block
    if ( 'core/post-template' !== $block['blockName'] ) return $block_content;

    // do something with $block_content (here we prepend a paragraph to each listed entry)
    $block_content=str_replace("<li ", "<p>Hello world!</p><li ", $block_content);

    return $block_content;
}
```